# Ideal configuration for two Proxmox 4.1 nodes cluster

Tags: proxmox, drbd

The Situation: I have two identical Supermicro servers with a lot of RAM and storage capacity. The servers got an Adaptec RAID Controller, which was used to create a RAID 1 for the OS and a RAID 50 for "data". The raid sets are identical on both servers. The servers also have built-in IPMI, which can be used for hardware watchdog on Proxmox (for fencing purposes).

I want both servers being a Proxmox VE node, and both servers should have the very same data on it. That's why data replication is a must. In case one server is down, the second one should be able to serve the VMs and Containers. As per Proxmox wiki, three nodes are required for HA, but I only have two of these.

What I did so far is to get Proxmox 4.1 installed on both servers and created a XFS partition on both machines, which is mirrored synchronously via DRBD. That way, the data is replicated in real-time. However, it turns out that this is pretty slow on the VMs when writing many small files (the two servers are connected via 10Gbit for DRBD purposes. When writing large files, the troughput on that interface is about 1.04 Gbit/s.

Is there any way to improve the I/O troughput, or are there any other recommendations to build a better setup for this?

Comment: This link should help.   https://aresu.dsi.cnrs.fr/spip.php?article198